# How to make horizontal layout that is based on percentage?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm trying to make UITableViewCell for table that has multiple columns/ labels inside of it. For example the first column is 30 %, the 2nd one is 30 % and the third one is 40 % no matter what is the screen size.

I've tried with horizontal stack view and also adding constraints manually but it still didn't work.

Comment: Initially it sounds like you may want a UICollectionView where you set cell size based off of what your parent view dimensions are.

Comment: When you added constraints manually was it something like `columnOnelabel.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(cell.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.30).active = true`?

Comment: Not really, I only tried simple ones like setting the width or spacing to the nearest neighbor until I found its not enough, I'll try to learn UICollectionView I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Very easy. You will have 3 UIView's inside the cell. Place the first one to left. Pin top, bottom, and left to the cell. Control drag from UIView to the cell and select equal widths. This means that the UIView width will be equal to the cell width. We don't want that but first you do this.

Then, select the equal width constraint on the left pane and on the right pane change the multiplier value from 1 to 0.3 which means 30%. And repeat for the other UIViews.

For the last UIView, I pinned to top, bottom and RIGHT and the width multiplier is 0.4 for 40%

And you put whatever you want in to each UIView.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This a classic scenario handled only by collectionview properly you can handle it by tableview but it will very messy as you would have to implement multiple conditions in cellforrow delegate method